# How to do Top N per time bucket in KQL?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to group by time bucket and one other column and then only select the top N aggregated rows.
It's best explained with this example:

```
let T = datatable(d:datetime , continent:string, country:string, val:int)
[
    datetime(2022-10-05T01:40:00.00), "Asia", "China", 10,
    datetime(2022-10-05T02:50:00.00), "Asia", "India", 25,
    datetime(2022-10-05T03:55:00.00), "Asia", "Japan", 15,
    datetime(2022-10-05T01:40:00.00), "Europe", "Czech Republic", 1,
    datetime(2022-10-05T02:50:00.00), "Europe", "France", 8,
    datetime(2022-10-05T07:55:00.00), "Europe", "Germany", 9,
    datetime(2022-10-05T04:55:00.00), "North America", "USA", 25,
    datetime(2022-10-05T05:55:00.00), "North America", "Haiti", 5,
    datetime(2022-10-05T09:55:00.00), "North America", "Jamaica", 3,
    datetime(2022-10-06T01:40:00.00), "Asia", "China", 7,
    datetime(2022-10-06T02:50:00.00), "Asia", "India", 8,
    datetime(2022-10-06T03:55:00.00), "Asia", "Japan", 15,
    datetime(2022-10-06T01:40:00.00), "Europe", "Czech Republic", 29,
    datetime(2022-10-06T02:50:00.00), "Europe", "France", 14,
    datetime(2022-10-06T07:55:00.00), "Europe", "Germany", 13,
    datetime(2022-10-06T04:55:00.00), "North America", "USA", 12,
    datetime(2022-10-06T05:55:00.00), "North America", "Haiti", 7,
    datetime(2022-10-06T09:55:00.00), "North America", "Jamaica", 4,
];
T
| summarize sumval = sum(val) by bin(d,1d), continent
| sort by d asc, sumval desc
```

This is the result, but I only want the top 2 results per day (highlighted).

[image]

In SQL I would use either `row_number` or `cross apply`, but I've been struggling in KQL. I want to understand the solution, because it doesn't *click* yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[top-nested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/topnestedoperator) operator

Please note that in you case you don't really need the 1st `sum(val)`, but it was added since the syntax mandates something there.
We could have used `count()`, `0`, `int(null)` or other options for that matter.

```
let T = datatable(d:datetime , continent:string, country:string, val:int)
[
    datetime(2022-10-05T01:40:00.00), "Asia", "China", 10,
    datetime(2022-10-05T02:50:00.00), "Asia", "India", 25,
    datetime(2022-10-05T03:55:00.00), "Asia", "Japan", 15,
    datetime(2022-10-05T01:40:00.00), "Europe", "Czech Republic", 1,
    datetime(2022-10-05T02:50:00.00), "Europe", "France", 8,
    datetime(2022-10-05T07:55:00.00), "Europe", "Germany", 9,
    datetime(2022-10-05T04:55:00.00), "North America", "USA", 25,
    datetime(2022-10-05T05:55:00.00), "North America", "Haiti", 5,
    datetime(2022-10-05T09:55:00.00), "North America", "Jamaica", 3,
    datetime(2022-10-06T01:40:00.00), "Asia", "China", 7,
    datetime(2022-10-06T02:50:00.00), "Asia", "India", 8,
    datetime(2022-10-06T03:55:00.00), "Asia", "Japan", 15,
    datetime(2022-10-06T01:40:00.00), "Europe", "Czech Republic", 29,
    datetime(2022-10-06T02:50:00.00), "Europe", "France", 14,
    datetime(2022-10-06T07:55:00.00), "Europe", "Germany", 13,
    datetime(2022-10-06T04:55:00.00), "North America", "USA", 12,
    datetime(2022-10-06T05:55:00.00), "North America", "Haiti", 7,
    datetime(2022-10-06T09:55:00.00), "North America", "Jamaica", 4,
];
T
| top-nested of bin(d, 1d) by sum(val), top-nested 2 of continent by sum(val)
```

| d | aggregated_d | continent | aggregated_continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-05T00:00:00Z | 101 | Asia | 50 |
| 2022-10-05T00:00:00Z | 101 | North America | 33 |
| 2022-10-06T00:00:00Z | 109 | Europe | 56 |
| 2022-10-06T00:00:00Z | 109 | Asia | 30 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6WUzWuDMBjG74L/w0tPFuqIaW3XjB3K2FcPO2zdaewQNVsDGiXGQcf%20%20CUt6we2b4XpwUfJ7/HhzUNyYWAB15BxY%208kF0HGrBZGFgIGkJbKSCWUYbXRUn26L40yerV9/%20I5k8r0fe/N98Bef3RACaVhREISL0jERoQRckFIfwC9WS15zz5vllI5EZEBwlIWH2EfVbYWNMbYIYvjNjvnFVfuvyh7mPm20WUl1qm/RbqEZ1E1SS5TZ9M9/c7lTnOVOnWJ0ZOD/Dv6XuiCq5WVUwwfHeBPpTZLmBVCy3Q9h9eX2dkJxrjFA5dGWoF6THGPOS/4Rg5PuozPdWiCoXiFTu/A%20B8NaiVGGkRP72Ir/ZEKRSMMP9%20hCJ17pxJFFLPoWCJ0DzuXyA3j/cr3Fr73A6asQiVqIzIoPyCRKshs2KwPyQrqpgjs8WXt9lZRt2577O0v%20wX5NfRkKwUAAA==)

Comment: Thank you. What confused me was the change of syntax. Summarize is aggregation by group. top-nested is group by aggregation. And it seems like it can group by only one column per level